# Unable to bind DropDownListFor in a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that loads as a modal in other view.

Code in Partial View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modal => modal.CompanyName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "CompanyName", "CompanyName"), "Select Company")
```

And Action Result-

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    Contacts_VM vm = new Contacts_VM();
    using (Entities xContext = new Entities())
    {
        ViewBag.Companies = new SelectList(xContext.Companies.ToList(), "CompanyName", "CompanyName");
    }
    return PartialView("~/Views/Contact/_AddEdit.cshtml", vm);
}
```

Using above code I'm getting error message-

> DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'CompanyName'.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewBag.Companies` is already a `SelectList`, so passing it to the constructor of another `SelectList` in the partial view is incorrect.  You should just be able to pass it through:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modal => modal.CompanyName, (SelectList)ViewBag.Companies, "Select Company")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the view code to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modal => modal.CompanyName, (SelectList)ViewBag.Companies)
```

The `ViewBag` property is already `SelectList` so there is no point creating another identical one from it (but if you did, it would need to be `new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Value", "Text")`)